# Using Match to return value from one of 9 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

This formula works for a single column:
`=IFERROR(MATCH([@[TerminalID]],tblMaster[LOCATION_ID 1],0),"No ID Match")`

This works unless the matched value is in tblMaster[LOCATION_ID 2] through *ID 9]

I tried the following answer ([Use Index Match to Return Value Using Lookup Value from Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281226/use-index-match-to-return-value-using-lookup-value-from-multiple-columns)) but it is very bulky for 9 columns.

Can I make the `MATCH`function search multiple columns?

For what it is worth, I have also tried the following:
`=IFERROR(MATCH([@[Terminal ID]],tblMaster[[LOCATION_ID 1]:[LOCATION_ID 9]],0),"No ID Match")`
and
`=IFERROR(MATCH([@[Terminal ID]],'Master List'!O:W,0),"No ID Match")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(tblMaster[[LOCATION_ID 1]:[LOCATION_ID 9]])/([@[Terminal ID]]=tblMaster[[LOCATION_ID 1]:[LOCATION_ID 9]]),1),"No ID Match")
```

Comment: Scott - brilliant...except the formula returns a value of 2 when the [@Terminal ID]] is empty or blank and I would expect the "No ID Match" to display.  Any ideas?

Comment: Add and IF() wrapper to test if the terminal id is `""` and return `""` if TRUE and the result of the the above formula if not.